# webpage could not be loaded because net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js

we are using vue ui to manage a fresh vue project (vue cli 3) included vue-router, vuex and cordova plugins. we run the command 'npm run cordova-serve-android' and app be open in my device but webpage not available.

we tried open url in browser of PC: https://10.253.29.21:8081 . this url after security alerts be open and request some info in fields that are filled automatically! I press enter(for 2 or 3 times) then web page be open my app but in android device no!

Note: device and PC connected to same Wifi modem and internet connection.

Comment: Where you able to get this resolved?  I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may still have problems with your router setup. I would check corresponding options for allowing local devices to be discover-able on both your PC and router.

Comment: note that in PC browser, URL is https://localhost:8081/#/ . but error in android device is looking for this url: https://10.253.29.21:8081/

Comment: is possible to give url manually to vue js for running that url in cordova?

Comment: Also I tested fresh app without router plugin. still have same error

Comment: in pc browser asks 3 times script prompt!

Comment: 3 script prompts in PC browser: 1: gap_init:3 2:gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","messageChannel","CoreAndroid151520030"] 3: gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","show","CoreAndroid151520031"] ... also alert me the page is not secure!